# method returns the same lots of times

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Database

```js
sequelize.sync().then(function () {
    keywordTitle.create({
        Title: 'ceo',
        userId: 1
    })
});
```

server.js

```js
              keywordTitle.findAll({where: {userId: req.user.id}}).then((keywordsTitle) => {
                let titleFromDB = keywordsTitle.map(title => title.dataValues.Title);
                titleFromDB.forEach(userTitle => {
                  console.log(userTitle)
                })
              })
```

It's supposed to return only the `ceo` once but returns it more times.

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `Title`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `userId` FROM `keywordTitles` AS `keywordTitle` WHERE `keywordTitle`.`userId` = 1;
ceo
ceo
ceo
ceo
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `Title`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `userId` FROM `keywordTitles` AS `keywordTitle` WHERE `keywordTitle`.`userId` = 1;
ceo
ceo
ceo
ceo
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `Title`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `userId` FROM `keywordTitles` AS `keywordTitle` WHERE `keywordTitle`.`userId` = 1;
ceo
ceo
ceo
ceo
```

Comment: What's inside your `keywordTitles` table?

Comment: If you are getting single entity then make sure you use function to retrieve single result. For example, you can use `findOne()` function. Also make sure that all ID's have unique values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if userId is unique. It seems that you have multiple records with the same userId.

If you want to return a single record use the findOne function

```
keywordTitle.findOne({where: {userId: req.user.id}})
    .then(keywordTitle => {
        if (!keywordTitle) {
            // If the title cannot be found it will be null
            return;
        }
        const titleFromDB = keywordTitle.Title;
        console.log(titleFromDB);
    });
});
```

One thing to have in mind is that if you have multiple keyword titles with the same userId the above function will return only the first record

Comment: I have multiple keywords under the same userId, how can I show them all?